# .cs file with Strings.Right in C# Windows App works, but same .cs file in C# Console Application doesn't compile Strings.Right

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Forms app .cs file in which at the top is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System;  
using System.Linq;      
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Diagnostics;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Xml.Linq;  
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;  
using System.Collections;  
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

..and in the code there is:

```
if (Strings.Right(PROGRAM_SOURCE_PATH, 7) == "\\Debug\\")
```

and "Strings" compiles ok.

But when I copy this .cs file into my C# Console Application, I get:
"The name 'Strings' does not exist in the current context" even though 
using `Microsoft.VisualBasic;` it's still at the top.

Even if I start a new C# Windows Forms app project, and copy the .cs file over, it gets same error for Strings.Right.

Comment: Don't use the VisualBasic library, it only exists to preserve compatibility with old code, use `Substring`

Comment: If you really need a `.Right()` function, write an Extension method.

Comment: @Gusman - While I agree with your suggestion to use `Substring` (since this is about C#), the classes in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace are not just for compatibility.  They are part of Visual Basic and Microsoft has no plans to remove them as far as I am aware.  There is an assembly called `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility` which does contain compatibility classes and are marked as obsolete and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it and it works in a console application. Have you add the assembly reference in the project?
[image: Console app with Microsoft.VisualBasic reference]

Comment: VS2017 Pro > File > New > proj > Console App.  Then copy .cs class to project folder. Then (answer below) proj > add > exist item > .cs....... Strings. and FileSystem. "..does not exist in current context".............. I see problem: "Microsoft.VisualBasic" missing in my Refs list....BINGO!

Answer (score 0):

Did you just copy it into the project without using right-click on the Project -> Add -> Class? Because if you did it doesn't compile?

Comment: I indeed did that.  Proj > right-click > add > existing item > .cs (class)